# Navigation Bar with on hover drop down

Tags: html, css, jsfiddle, navigationbar

When I hover at submenu items: LUNCH MENU/DINNER MENU, is there a way that the 'MENUS' remain at this style :`(background color: #666699, color: white)`

I tried to solve it but to no avail. Can anyone give me some idea on how to implement this? I have included the jsfiddle link at the comment.

http://jsfiddle.net/tangjeen/je24e85w/#base

Thanks.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tangjeen/je24e85w/#base

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this: http://jsfiddle.net/je24e85w/2/

```
#menu:hover > * {   background-color: #666699; color: white; }
```

This css will make it so when you hover #menu, it and it's children will get the correct hover styles.

Comment: No problem, please be sure to mark this as the answer once you've verified the fix.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
.nonDropDown li:hover>a {
  background: blue;
  color: #fff !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't work, the above code changes the submenu items as I hover over it. I am wondering if it is possible to change the MENUS, when I hover at submenu

Comment: If you could please edit your answer and explain what the code you're showing does, and why/how that code answers the question, it could really help.

Comment: @noob, It works, thanks! Can I know what does >a means?

Comment: @Jeen I thought you found richie's ans right. In that case how did my ans work for you as both of our answers are different and produce different results!!